# Properties of Coefficients of Order Polynomials

Tags: convex-polytopes, order-theory, posets, algebraic-combinatorics

I am working on a problem involving determining the order polynomial $\Omega_P(k)$ of a partial order $P$, which counts the number of order-preserving transformations/maps from $P$ to the $k$-chain (containing $k$ points and with length $(k-1)$). I'm aware that various sources (e.g., *Handbook of Enumerative Combinatorics* by Bona, 2015) show that
$$\Omega_P(k)=a_nk^n+a_{n-1}k^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1k+a_0,$$

where $n=|P|$ and $a_n=e(P)/|P|!$. Here, $e(P)$ denotes the number of linear extensions of $P$. My question is, what else is known about the remaining coefficients $a_{n-1},\ldots,a_1,a_0$? In particular, I am assuming that $n=k$ (thus thinking of both the poset and the chain length as functions of $n$), and am hoping to prove something of the form

$$\Omega_P(n)=\Theta(n^n),$$

which will be useful.

Besides the main problem, I am also interested in any known closed form expressions of order polynomials for special classes of posets. (E.g., if $P=P_{N,r}$, the graded disjoint union of $N$ chains having $r$ elements each, then $\Omega_P(k)={r+k-1\choose k-1}^N$; see [Reiner, Stanton and Welker 2003](http://www.math.umn.edu/~reiner/Papers/CDNSStanton.pdf))

(P.S. I posted this on [StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411764/properties-of-coefficients-of-order-polynomials) earlier, but realised that there weren't any specific tags that would facilitate the reach of the question to the hands of the appropriate audience.)

Comment: This fits into the larger setting of Ehrhart polynomials of lattice polytopes. The order polynomial is the Ehrhart polynomial of the order polytope.

Comment: I would say "various sources $\dots$ *show* $\dots$" rather than "suggest." I don't understand your question about $\Theta(a_nk^n)$. Are you fixing $P$ and letting $k\to\infty$? Every polynomial $f(k)$ of degree $n$ satisfies $f(k)=\Theta(k^n)$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this already has an answer on MSE.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. In the actual problem, we are taking $k=n$ (the poset $P$ and the chain $\mathbf{k}$ are related). Thus, the answer I am looking for isn't quite the one given in MSE.

Comment: There are basic rules to follow when posting a question on several sites. The first one being: Don't order pizza from two places at once just because you're hungry.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry if I have breached any rules. I have edited the problem statement to reflect the nature of the actual problem I'm working on.

Comment: If $P$ is an $n$-element chain then $\Omega_P(n)=\Theta(4^n/\sqrt{n})$.